# Google Search Console reports a page had a usability problem last week, how can I find out what page that was?

Tags: google-search-console, usability

Two weeks ago the Google search console emailed me about a mobile usability problem. I've just gotten around to investigating now.

The Google search console detected that the text was too small to read on one page between the 26th and the 31st of January. However, it could give no example URL of the page.

If this wasn't a false alarm, how can I find out which page has the usability problem?

[image: Screenshot of Google Search Console]

Sorry for the Spanish in the screenshot. I don't know how to change the language of the console.

Comment: I'm not sure you can retrieve that info at this point.

Comment: False alarms are common for that issue in particular (text too small). I wouldn't worry about it unless it's a current warning with examples given. Although... there is a small chance that your site really did have a problem that fixed itself. If you have issues with CSS you'll get this 'text too small' warning whenever an important stylesheet fails on a crawler visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Steven Ostermiller's and Trich's comments:

- False alarms are common for this issue
- It's no longer possible to retrieve the URL

So that's it, nothing to worry about :-)